# Access Raspberry Pi3 Timer using Python

Tags: gpio, python, uart, interrupts, system-clock

there is a way to get access and then configure Raspberry pi Timers using a Python? I saw some code to do that but it always be in C. Like here [[BareMetal] Timer on Raspi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=9882)

All this I need to send files via UART but I want complete controll on it. I want to know and manage all interrupts etc.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know and manage all interrupts etc.

There is no way to achieve what you want under Linux.  Linux handles all interrupts.

That being the case you will need to go bare metal or find an operating system which gives you control over interrupts (I doubt one exists).